# Running a command through a tty without commenting out "requiretty"

Tags: centos, sudo, jenkins

I'm running the latest version of Jenkins on CentOS.  In my Jenkins job, I can run post build steps, and included this command,

```
sudo /bin/rm /usr/java/jboss/server/default/deploy/myclient-1.0.war
```

which dies with the error

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Is there a way I can rewrite the above to run the command through a tty shell?  In our /etc/sudoers file, we have the line

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

but our sysadmin has forbade us from commenting it out.

Comment: Is there some reason you have to deploy as `root`? It sounds like you and the sysadmin need to have a long talk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/usr/java/jboss/server/default/deploy/myclient-1.0.war` has to be removed by root you might be doing something wrong. I can't think of a good reason that file would need to be owned by root.

The other option is to see how your sysadmin feels about disabling requiretty for that one command.

```
Cmnd_Alias           NOTTYCMD = /bin/rm /usr/java/jboss/server/default/deploy/myclient-1.0.war
Defaults!NOTTYCMD   !requiretty
```

Comment: Could you explain your comment " ...  has to be removed by root you might be doing something wrong "?  The files in the deploy directory are owned by the 'jboss' user with 755 perms and Jenkins runs under user 'jenkins'.

Comment: @Dave Since the file is owned by `jboss` then it can be removed by `jboss`. No need to involve root.

Answer (score 1):

> but our sysadmin has forbade us from commenting it out.

He can disable only for the `jenkins` user:

```
Defaults:jenkins    !requiretty
```

> The files in the deploy directory are owned by the `jboss` user with
>   755 perms and Jenkins runs under user `jenkins`.

or make the `deploy` folder group writable and set the SGID bit:

```
chmod -R g+w /usr/java/jboss/server/default/deploy/
chmod g+s /usr/java/jboss/server/default/deploy/
```

and add the `jenkins` user to the `jboss` group:

```
usermod -a -G jboss jenkins
```

then you can delete `/usr/java/jboss/server/default/deploy/myclient-1.0.war` without using `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too when trying to start jboss as jboss user. The problem was solved by changing a line in the file /etc/init.d/jboss in the following way:

before:
su - $JBOSS_USER -c "LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT -c $JBOSS_CONFIG" 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG &

after:
su - $JBOSS_USER -c "LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT -c $JBOSS_CONFIG 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG &"